# How to get Latitude and longitude from a click on the map?

Tags: angular5

Hi everyone im trying to add the possibility that the user can get the latitude and longitude from a  click  and get the lat and longitude in the fields : this is my html part :

```
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class=" panel panel-primary" style="background-color: darkgray;" >
        <div class="panel-heading">Position :</div>
        <div class="panel-body">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Adresse :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pan.adresse"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Latitude</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pan.latitude"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Longitude :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pan.longitude"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Etat :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pan.etat"/>
          </div>

        </div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class=" panel panel-primary"  >
        <div class="panel-heading">Map :</div>
        <div class="panel-body">

          <agm-map [latitude]="36.718241" [longitude]="3.091969" [zoom]="6">
          </agm-map>

        </div></div>
    </div>
```

so i have the map and the input related to latitude and longitude, instead of writing the informations i want to replace that by a  click on the map and the fields will be full automatically 
thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapClick` event to retrieve lat and lng of place where the user has clicked, and assign that information to variables which are being accessed in template

```
 <agm-map (mapClick)="mapClick($event)" [latitude]="36.718241" [longitude]="3.091969" [zoom]="6">
 </agm-map>
```

In .ts file add

```
mapClick($event) {
this.pan.latitude = $event.lat();
this.pan.longtitude = $event.lng();
}
```

[mapClick](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/AgmMap.html#mapClick) [Latlng](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/interfaces/LatLng.html)